# How to boot from a USB floppy drive on a UEFI BIOS

Tags: boot, usb, ms-dos, floppy, freedos

I have a RAAYOO USB floppy drive reader and some generic 1.44 MB floppy disks. I am trying to boot FREEDOS Floppy Edition using this reader on a computer with a UEFI BIOS. It shows up under legacy boot options, but when I click on it, it freezes and refuses to boot, even after 10 minutes. I verified the files, tried flashing using other tools, tried MS-DOS instead, and tried it on an old Dell Mobile Workstation, but nothing will boot. I can copy, read, and write to text documents and other files, for some reason, I just can't get it to boot. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to install it on real hardware.

Comment: USB floppy drives can't be used as boot drives. Something between the typical diskette bootloader and the USB mass storage device emultion those drives depend on is "lost in translation".

Answer (score 1):

One of the [FreeDOS requirements](https://www.freedos.org/download/) is

> BIOS or UEFI "Legacy" mode

This means it necessarily requires a pre-2012 BIOS based computer or a newer one that still supports Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode ("emulates" a real BIOS).

As commented by @John, "install FreeDOS as a virtual machine" is indeed the currently recommended way. However, if you really want to install it in bare metal (or "real hardware" as they say) then you need to choose the installation options accordingly to the target hardware.

The floppy disks option is intended only for 1980s computers with standard diskette drives. Quoting:

> This edition should run on any original IBM PC system, including the PC, XT, and AT.

**Your options are CD or USB and the latter is strongly recommended.** It comes in two "flavors", self-explanatory: FullUSB or LiteUSB. Follow instructions from the download website. Personal recommendation, just extract the image file to a USB stick with [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) previously installed